# Android Studio not working correctly

Tags: android

My Android Studio Emulator not working correctly it is going disabled in 4 to 5 seconds after execution how can i fix this problem please reply soon

Comment: screenshot of the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about an Android emulatot aren't programming issues or problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Android Studio to the latest version or using another emulator such as https://www.genymotion.com/ instead.